# Inputenc error with bibliography: unicode character (U+009D)

Tags: latex, bibliography, texstudio

I am trying to compile a "book" document with its bibliography, but each time I compile it with TeXstudio I get the same error: "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+009D) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX". My bibliography is contained in one .bib file. What should I do to correct this error? In particular, what does the unicode character (U+009D) stand for? Thank you in advance to anybody answering!

Comment: Make a copy of the whole directory of your project and then keep deleting half of the bibliography until you isolated the offending entry.

Answer (score 1):

I put the text (that occurs this mistake) in Notepad++ and deleted the found wrong character. Then it would work after copying them back.